# Chaining If conditions with && operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code - which carries out a variety of state checks:

```
CheckValStates= () => {

  _stateCheck = val => {
    if (!val || val == '' ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };


if (
      this._stateCheck(this.state.arReason) ||
      this._stateCheck(this.state.handoverType) ||
      (this.state.handoverType === 'CUSTOMER' &&
        this._stateCheck(this.state.staffHandoverDeets)) ||
      (this.state.handoverType === 'GUARD' &&
        this._stateCheck(this.state.keyStatus) &&
        this._stateCheck(this.state.staticOfficerHandover))
    ) {
     return true;
    }

  return false;
  };
}
```

I was having issues with the following line:

```
(this.state.handoverType === 'GUARD' &&
        this._stateCheck(this.state.keyStatus) &&
        this._stateCheck(this.state.staticOfficerHandover))
)
```

Returns true if only the first 2 elements are true - the 3rd check (`this._stateCheck(this.state.staticOfficerHandover)`) is ignored.  I was expecting all three checks to match for a true result.

If i replace that chained statement with -

```
if (


      this._stateCheck(this.state.arReason) ||
      this._stateCheck(this.state.handoverType) ||
      (this.state.handoverType === 'CUSTOMER' &&
        this._stateCheck(this.state.staffHandoverDeets)) ||

      (this.state.handoverType === 'GUARD' && this._stateCheck(this.state.keyStatus) || this.state.handoverType === 'GUARD' && this._stateCheck(this.state.staticOfficerHandover) )
    )
```

it carries out the check as expected.  I'd like to understand why.

Comment: That would imply an issues with the `&&` operator which is very unlikely. How do you know that the third operand is not evaluated? And/or that the condition resulted in `true`?

Comment: you could add a `console.log(val)` in `_stateCheck `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your function `_stateCheck` is not perfect : some values can cause problem.

```js
stateCheck(null) // true
stateCheck(undefined) // true
stateCheck("") // true
stateCheck({}) // false
stateCheck([]) // true  - possible problem
stateCheck(true) // false
stateCheck(false) // true - possible problem
stateCheck(0) // true - possible problem
stateCheck(-10) // false
stateCheck(10) // false
```

If `this.state.staticOfficerHandover` was a problematic value, `stateCheck` will send `true`

Example:

```js
const stateCheck = val => {
    if (!val || val == '' ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };


const state = {
    handoverType: "GUARD",
    keyStatus : "",
    staticOfficerHandover: true,
}

const condition = (state.handoverType === 'GUARD' &&
 stateCheck(state.keyStatus) &&
 stateCheck(state.staticOfficerHandover)
 )
console.log(condition); // false

state.staticOfficerHandover = false;
const condition2 = (state.handoverType === 'GUARD' &&
 stateCheck(state.keyStatus) &&
 stateCheck(state.staticOfficerHandover)
 )
 console.log(condition2); // true
```

Comment: Sorry - just seen this @n4n5 - grteat answer - thank you.  I'll trace through all code checksand alter.  thanks for your help/.